# Why not construction-time block size for boost::deque?

Tags: c++, data-structures, boost, memory-management, deque

Why [`boost::container::deque`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/container/deque.html) requires the block size to be specified at cmpile-time? Wouldn't construction-time specification be enough?

What exactly the implementation does that would be impossible with the construction-time specification of the block size (number of items in each block)?

Comment: Why do you think it had to be compile time?  It could totally have been construction time if desired.  There's just very little benefit to doing so, as it would be slightly slower, and callers would be prone to picking poor block sizes.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think just the opposite. I think it would be better to be construction-time! Now it is to be specified via the third template parameter called `Options`. Also, why the users will tend to specify the bock size more frequently if it would be construction-time rather than it is type-definition-time (compile-time, like it is now)?

Comment: Right now, at a glance, I don't even see how to specify the block size. They made it complex on purpose, so that people wouldn't override it (because people usually pick poor block sizes).  Devs will specify more frequently in the constructor due to [Hyrum's Law](https://www.hyrumslaw.com/).  Right now, the block size is hard coded, so the code can take shortcuts with division, and since it's a small power of two, there's lots of shortcuts available. If it's user provided, the code can't take any shortcuts, and must do full slow division every time. Much slower.

Comment: It might be the next power of two for the specified block size :)

Comment: But the compiler won't know that, all it knows is that the size is an `int`. so the compiler has to generate the full slow division code regardless, because the developer _might_ provide a weird value.

Comment: I mean, the code might still use shifts, by `ceil(log2(the-specified-size))`.

Comment: @Vahgan: No, because that would waste up to half the memory, or use a bigger size than specified, and in both cases, the elements-per-block is _still_ an unknown integer at compile time, so it _still_ can't take shortcuts in the math, and would be slower. And again: There's no benefit.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, it will use bigger block size than specified and the performance overhead will be shifting vs shortcuts. But the benefit of the ability to specify the block size at construction-time would be picking a better block size based on the knowledge that is not available at compile-time. E.g. for a FIFO buffer that is going to have roughly 1000-1100 items, specifying block size as 128 items would eliminate any reallocation, but the information about the expected size of the buffer might be available at construction-time and not at compile-time.

Comment: @Vahagn Besides more complicated runtime math you will also have more overhead with iterators, which now have to contain either the block size or a pointer to the parent deque as a member. And the next thing you'll want is to set the block size after construction, which is whole another level of complexity. If you really do need a runtime block size, you may want a different container.

Comment: @AndreySemashev For sure, setting the block size after construction is another level of complexity, and I don't think we will refer to such a container as deque. As mentioned above, my motivation is obtaining *non-reallocating FIFO buffer*. But as pointed out here, https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/hPHs98Z7X-g/EgzTBkVvCgAJ it seems all the available implementations deallocate early (I've checked with boost's version too)! This is a bit of surprise, and unfortunately, it makes the motivation senseless.

Comment: @Vahagn: `std::deque` is optimized around constant time push_back and push_front. If you want a non-reallocating FIFO buffer, and you know a maximum size, then what you want is probably a circular buffer. If you don't have a maximum size, then you need reallocating.

Comment: Circular buffer is not an option for me by another reason. But having an option like `number-of-freed-blocks-to-reuse` for  `boost::container::deque` would perfectly solve the issue. I don't see any drawbacks that will be added to the existing solution because of supporting such option.